# Widget and Main menu - selected state - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

Here's the deal:

Wordpress website: 
http://www.spectrum-aerospace.com/services/engineering/

On the mentioned link the Engineering tab has the selected state  (mouse hover the tab Services please). As you can see I have another menu on the right.

What I want is that the selected state of "Engineering" on the Main menu also affects the widget menu so I have the "selected" style information on both menus.

The bottom end is that they are different menus so I'm kinda stuck in here.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here`s the solution:

li.current-menu-item a {

}